# moving an image across a html canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to move an image from the right to the center and I am not sure if this is the best way.

```
var imgTag = null;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var id;

    function doCanvas()
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('icanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var imgBkg = document.getElementById('imgBkg');
        imgTag = document.getElementById('imgTag');

        ctx.drawImage(imgBkg, 0, 0);

        x = canvas.width;
        y = 40;

        id = setInterval(moveImg, 0.25);

    }

    function moveImg()
    {
        if(x <= 250)
            clearInterval(id);

        var canvas = document.getElementById('icanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var imgBkg = document.getElementById('imgBkg');
        ctx.drawImage(imgBkg, 0, 0);

        ctx.drawImage(imgTag, x, y);

        x = x - 1;
    }
```

Any advice?

Comment: setInterval takes in a number of milliseconds, not seconds.  The practical lower limit for most browsers is around 10ms.

Answer (score 15):

This question is 5 years old, but since we now have `requestAnimationFrame()` method, here's an approach for that using vanilla JavaScript:

```js
var imgTag = new Image(),
    canvas = document.getElementById('icanvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    x = canvas.width,
    y = 0;

imgTag.onload = animate;
imgTag.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk0DW.png";   // load image

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  // clear canvas
  ctx.drawImage(imgTag, x, y);                       // draw image at current position
  x -= 4;
  if (x > 250) requestAnimationFrame(animate)        // loop
}
```

```html
<canvas id="icanvas" width=640 height=180></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

`drawImage()` enables to define which part of the source image to draw on target canvas. I would suggest for each `moveImg()` calculate the previous image position, overwrite the previous image with that part of `imgBkg`, then draw the new image. Supposedly this will save some computing power.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var myImg = new Image();
var myImgPos = {
  x: 250,
  y: 125,
  width: 50,
  height: 25
}

function draw() {
  myImg.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(myImg, myImgPos.x, myImgPos.y, myImgPos.width, myImgPos.height);
  }

  myImg.src = "https://mario.wiki.gallery/images/thumb/c/cc/NSMBUD_Mariojump.png/1200px-NSMBUD_Mariojump.png";
}

function moveMyImg() {
  ctx.clearRect(myImgPos.x, myImgPos.y, myImgPos.x + myImgPos.width, myImgPos.y +
    myImgPos.height);
  myImgPos.x -= 5;
}

setInterval(draw, 50);
setInterval(moveMyImg, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="250" height="150"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

For lag free animations,i generally use kinetic.js.

```
 var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var hexagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
        x: stage.width()/2,
        y: stage.height()/2,
        sides: 6,
        radius: 70,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
      });

      layer.add(hexagon);
      stage.add(layer);

      var amplitude = 150;
      var period = 2000;
      // in ms
      var centerX = stage.width()/2;

      var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
        hexagon.setX(amplitude * Math.sin(frame.time * 2 * Math.PI / period) + centerX);
      }, layer);

      anim.start();
```

Here's the example,if you wanna take a look.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-animate-position-tutorial/

Why i suggest this is because,setInterval or setTimeout a particular function causes issues when large amount of simultaneous animations take place,but **kinetic.Animation** deals with framerates **more intelligently.**

Answer (score 0):

### Explaining `window.requestAnimationFrame()` with an example

In the following snippet I'm using an image for the piece that is going to be animated.

I'll be honest...  `window.requestAnimationFrame()` wasn't easy for me to understand, that is why I coded it as clear and intuitive as possible. So that you may struggle less than I did to get my head around it.

```js
const 
  canvas = document.getElementById('root'),
  btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  brickImage = new Image(),
  piece = {image: brickImage, x:400, y:70, width:70};
  
brickImage.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/YreH6.png";
     
// When btn is clicked execute start()     
btn.addEventListener('click', start) 

function start(){
    btn.value = 'animation started'  
    
    // Start gameLoop()
    brickImage.onload = window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop) 
}

function gameLoop(){ 
  // Clear canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  
  // Draw at coordinates x and y
  ctx.drawImage(piece.image, piece.x, piece.y)     
  
  let pieceLeftSidePos = piece.x;
  let middlePos = canvas.width/2 - piece.width/2;
  
  // Brick stops when it gets to the middle of the canvas
  if(pieceLeftSidePos > middlePos) piece.x -= 2;

  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)   // Needed to keep looping
}
```

```html
<input id="btn" type="button" value="start" />
<p>
<canvas id="root" width="400" style="border:1px solid grey">
```

**A key point**

Inside the **start()** function we have:

```
brickImage.onload = window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
```

This could also be written like: `window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);`
and it would probably work, but I'm adding the `brickImage.onload` to make sure that the image has loaded first. If not it could cause some issues.

**Note:** `window.requestAnimationFrame()` usually loops at 60 times per second.