# Changing Image Position drawn with canvas drawImage function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to use canvas `drawImage()` function to drawImages and then change each image's position dynamically.

The image gets drawn fine but I am not being able to change its respective position (x,y) in the canvas, dynamically.

[image: an example image]

There will be more than 1 such icons (camera images) and I want to have the ability to move each icon according to the user-specified position.

**Note:** The user will specify the position via some input field (and not by mouse click event).

**Sample Code**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = new Image()
image.src = '/static/camera.png'
image.onload = () => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 10, 10)
}
```

TBH I am not sure if that's even possible or not because I am not being able to find any related content/questions online?

if not, can someone point me in the right direction, please?

**[EDIT]**

Just to make clear, I don't want to re-render or redraw the entire canvas again, because it might hold other images too and that would be expansive, then. I am asking for a solution, other than redrawing with newer positions.

Comment: Did you check out this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057162/moving-an-image-across-a-html-canvas

Comment: I have now,  But my case is slightly different. I don't want to re-render or redraw the entire canvas again, because it might hold other images too and that would be expansive, then. I am asking for a solution, other than redrawing with newer positions.

Comment: @waleedali there is not other solution, you have to redraw the entire canvas or at least the part of the canvas that changed

Comment: How can I detect and redraw only the part of the canvas that changed?

Comment: Don't. You'll loose hair trying to do it right only to find out that it's more efficient to *clear everything and redraw* at every call.

Comment: Okay, thanks. BTW, is using canvas for this problem the right way? or shall I go for CSS?

Comment: @waleedali depends on what you want to achieve. Sometimes it's enough to use HTML + CSS, or SVG

Comment: As I said above, I have a number of images (cameras) which are added dynamically. I want to have the ability/functionality to change their positions (x, y) in the above grid.

Comment: As Helder and Kaiido suggested, I am now going for complete redrawing of canvas.